# What type of ailerons does the C172P have?

Tags: flight-controls, ppl, cessna-172

Today during the mock ground session with my instructor he asked what type of ailerons does the C172P have. I looked in section 7 of the POH and all I was able to find was "Conventional hinged ailerons" under the Airframe section. He said that it was not the correct answer and told me to go through the POH again to find out.

Are there any other official sources that I can find this info?

I'm leaning more towards the frise ailerons as I vaguely remember noticing that the leading edge of the up going aileron protrudes down pass the bottom of the wing.

Comment: If your instructor said you should find it in the POH then you should look in the POH.  That said, I fail to see how this knowledge would help make you a better pilot.

Comment: I have looked in the POH of various C172 models, and none of them mention anything other than  "Conventional hinged ailerons".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C172 is designed with “Piano Hinges” at the upper leading edge of the aileron, so even though the lower edge extends down a little bit, it is not a true Frise aileron.

They are also rigged so that the ailerons deflect more “Up” than the “Down”. Correct rigging gives 20° Up and 14° Down deflection at the control limit.

I would call them “Differential”, “Frise type” ailerons.

None of this is mentioned anywhere in the POH.

[“Writing by Valerie” photo](http://www.writingbyvalerie.com/cfi-preflighting-from-cotter-pins-to-piano-hinges-lesser-discussed-things-you-should-mention-and-look-at-on-your-flights-and-checkrides/)
[image: Writing by Valerie photo]

Comment: You make a good point.  They are actually a hybrid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they're frise ailerons if the bottom leading edge is ahead of the aileron hinge so that the bottom leading edge protrudes below the airfoil mold line when the aileron is up.